# Installing PyQt4.11.2 on Scientific Linux 6.5

Tags: python, linux, qt, installation, pyqt4

I know this is probably something trivial, but I cannot seem to find the answer. I have just completed a fresh install of Scientific Linux 6.5 - which ships with Python 2.6 and Qt 4.6.2. I wish to use the Python interpreter python2.7.8 so downloaded this and installed. I use the QtDesigner for ease when making guis, so then need the PyQt bindings to go with it. I therefore downloaded SIP-4.16.3, configured with:

## python2.7 ./configure (in the sip download directory)

to make the bindings for the newer version of python. Everything works fine so far.
I then try to install PyQt4.11.2 in the same way:

## python2.7 ./configure --qmake=/usr/lib/qt4/bin/qmake -g (to pick up the qt4 version of qmake with static qt libraries)

the configure script completes fine, but I get the following error during 'make':

error: ‘PrintCurrentPage’ is not a member of ‘QAbstractPrintDialog’
..../Downloads/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.11.2/QtGui/sipQtGuiQAbstractPrintDialog.cpp:1787: error: too many initializers for ‘sipEnumMemberDef’
make[1]: *** [sipQtGuiQAbstractPrintDialog.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `..../Downloads/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.11.2/QtGui'
make: *** [all] Error 2

I am at this point a little lost and have been bashing my head for a while, it must be something simple I have missed, any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My opinion: compiling qt (and related) is a royal pain, and you're better off getting a distribution adequate to your needs, in this case perhaps anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

1. Search string 'PrintCurrentPage' in files of your PyQt-package. You will find it in 4 files.
2. Remove corresponded lines with string 'PrintCurrentPage'

Comment: In the latest version of the installer, it's only on one file (QtGui/sipQtGuiQAbstractPrintDialog.cpp). I just removed the line in which PrincCurrentPage is declared and everything worked out perfectly (thanks for suggesting this solution!).

Comment: @Néstor That worked for me on Centos6 with python 2.7.11.  If you put that in an answer I'd vote for it

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but I ran into a similar error installing `PyQt4.11.4` by source on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 machine.

I ended up adding the members `'PrintShowPageSize = 0x0008'` and `'PrintCurrentPage = 0x0040'` to the class definition of `QAbstractPrintDialog`. This C++ class definition is located in the header file `qabstractprintdialog.h`. On my distribution, this was located in `/usr/lib64/qt4/include/QtGui/`.

After adding those missing members, I re-ran make with no compile errors.

The only reason I stumbled onto this solution was looking at this version of `qtabstractprintdialog.h` [here](https://github.com/openwebos/qt/blob/master/src/gui/dialogs/qabstractprintdialog.h). I noticed my version of the header file was missing those members in the `QAbstractPrintDialog` class.

I haven't put the new PyQt4 install to use yet, so I can't vouch for functionality just now. But it did compile/install!